# Web Image not displaying React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements, react-native-image

I'm trying to paste a link in a text box (TextInput) in React Native and it isn't displaying the image from the link.  I'm not sure where my mistake is . Please may someone help me out i'd really appreciate it . Thank you in advance!!!!!!!!!

Here's the code

```
const tryImage = "https://images.app.goo.gl/heFUyytHySGiSMeY8"
<View style={styles.info}>
    <Image source={one} style={styles.progress}/>
    <Text style={styles.title}>Add Photo</Text>
    <Image source={{uri: tryImage}} style={styles.icon}/>
</View>

icon:{
    width: 180,
    height: 180,
    marginTop: 50,
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry to delay.
Maybe your link has problem.
So you need to pass correct uri.
For example, now your link has not any extension such as png or jpg.
So please try with png.
For example: source={{uri: tryImage+'png'}}
I hope my answer will be help for you.